# Is there a circle tool for line features in ArcMap 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, editing

I want to draw a roundabout in a road map in ArcMap 10. They are usually perfectly round circles.

How can I do this?

I am struggling to find a good way to do this.

It takes ages with the Line tool and Curve tool.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one's a workaround

- Digitize roundabout as circle in a polygon layer
- Use [Polygon to Line Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003t000000) to convert it to a line feature
- Copy line feature to road layer

Would take a few steps but it should still be faster than fiddling around with the Line and Curve tool. Also found a tutorial on [creating roundabouts in the ESRI Resource Center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//022300000027000000) but unfortunately, they're not all that concerned about keeping it perfectly round ;-)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My problem (which I did not include in the question) is that i am editing in a geometric network which means that closed polylines is a no-go. I think, this calls for a home made circle draw tool.